# Add static data to existing django app --> migration? fixture? command?

Tags: django, csv, postgresql-9.1

We have a table with two cols: city and county. Using PostgreSQL 9.1

We found out there are a lot of missing cities there.
So I got a CSV file with a whole lot of such city / county entries.

What's the best way to add this data to the running app?

- I understand a migration supposedly should be best for schema changes. This is not the case here.
- A fixture seems the best option at first sight but there's no logic to fixtures, it's just json. I need the existing data to be left untouched, as it is referenced by id from other tables. And duplicates are of course not welcomed.
- The cleanest way seems to me to be a command, in which I can load the csv file and process entry by entry, adding a new one only if it's city element cannot be found.

Comment: You can do a Data Migration with South or even create a manage.py command to import your csv and create the necessary model instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [get_or_create()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) to do what you need through a management command or through a South [Data Migration](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part3.html). Here's an example of a management command:

```
import csv

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from your_app.models import YourModel


class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        with open('your-file.csv', 'rb') as csv_file:
        for row in csv_file:
            # you would need to know the column index to access as
            # csv reader returns a simple List for each row
            obj, created = YourModel.objects.get_or_create(field=row[0],
                defaults={'field': row[0]})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make a [south datamigration](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part3.html) which will import your data through ORM. 
You can do any logic there. For example checking for duplicates via `get_or_create()`